# Adding buttons dynamically to Java form

Tags: java, swing, sqlite

I'm making a Java program to save all of my website data.
The program is as follows.

I can add website ,url, login, password, ip, hosting etc. For that it creates a table "websiteinf".

Every time I add a new website. It automatically creates another new table in my database. The table is bl_websitename. For every website added, the table is different.
bl_website1, bl_website2... But it always starts with bl_.

I want to make another JFrame Form called backlinks.java

There I first want to add buttons for every table in my database starting with bl_

I want this to happen dynamically. So every time I register a new website. There automatically comes a new button in my backlinks.java Form.

I know how to do it manually. But I would like to know if its possible to create a button automatic when a new table starting with bl_ gets created.

Some help would be really nice on this one.

This is the code that adds the new website to my database table => Website
It automatically creates for each website a new database table => bl_mywebsite

```
     private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         


int x = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "This Will Add New Website!","Add New Website",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
if (x==0){




try { String sql ="insert into website " + "(website,url,login,password," + 
        "hostingaccount,hostingip,hostingusername," + "hostingpass) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) ";
pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
pst.setString(1,txt_website.getText());
pst.setString(2,txt_url.getText());
pst.setString(3,txt_login.getText());
pst.setString(4,txt_password.getText());
pst.setString(5,txt_hostingaccount.getText()); 
pst.setString(6,txt_hostingip.getText());
pst.setString(7,txt_hostingusername.getText()); 
pst.setString(8,txt_hostingpassword.getText());

pst.execute();

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Data is saved successfully"); 


       String add1 = txt_website.getText();

         String sql2 = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'bl_"+add1+"' (\n"
                + " id integer PRIMARY KEY,\n"
                 + "    fullurl text NOT NULL,\n"
                + " fromm text NOT NULL,\n"
                + " too text NOT NULL,\n"
                  + "   anchor text NOT NULL,\n"
                  + "   date text NOT NULL);";



        pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql2);
        pst.execute();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "New website backlink profile added:\n"+"Website: '"+add1+"'" );


} 
catch (Exception e) 
{ JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e); } 

finally 
{ try
{ rs.close(); pst.close(); } 
catch(Exception e){ } }
        // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                      
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }
```

This code is in addWebsite.java

What I would like to do is from inside addWebsite.java, create a button in backlinks.java Where the button name is going to be the name of the website is just added.

When I click on it I can then add new backlinks to the JFrame Form.
This I know how to do.

**The only thing I need help with is to create a button on backlinks.java when a new website is added on addWebsite.java and a new table bl_name-of-website is created.**

So I should to be able to write code in addWebsite.java that gets executed in backlinks.java

Im sorry if this is a bit confusing. But I don't really know a better way to explain. Im already looking for this for about 12 hours on the web :-)

```
   private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
int x = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "This Will Add New Backlink!","Add New Backlink",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
if (x==0){




try { String sql ="insert into bl_kruidenland (fromm,too,anchor) values (?,?,?) ";
pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
pst.setString(1,txt_blfrom.getText());
pst.setString(2,txt_blto.getText());
pst.setString(3,txt_anchor.getText());

pst.execute();

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Backlink is saved successfully"); 





} 
catch (Exception e) 
{ JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e); } 

finally 
{ try
{ rs.close(); pst.close(); } 
catch(Exception e){ } }
        // TODO add your handling code here:
}       






        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }
```

This is my backlinks.java where I added a button "kruidenland" myself manually. When the button gets clicked It adds the backlink information to the table bl_kruidenland.

I Would like that this button appears automatic when bl_somewebsite gets created. And then runs the same SQL automatic when button gets clicked. The only that changes is the table bl_kruidenland to table bl_SomeNewWebsiteIjustAdded.

Here I added a new button "Save" in backlinks.java

```
   private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         



int x = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "This Will Add New Backlink!","Add New Backlink",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
if (x==0){

String add1 = txt_search.getText();



try { String sql ="insert into bl_"+add1+" (fromm,too,anchor) values (?,?,?) ";
pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
pst.setString(1,txt_blfrom.getText());
pst.setString(2,txt_blto.getText());
pst.setString(3,txt_anchor.getText());

pst.execute();

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Backlink is saved successfully"); 





} 
catch (Exception e) 
{ JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e); } 

finally 
{ try
{ rs.close(); pst.close(); } 
catch(Exception e){ } }
        // TODO add your handling code here:
}
```

This way I am able to just type in the name of the website in a search bar. Without the extension or protocol (https and .com)

It will therefore use the table bl_SearchTextWhichIsTypedIn and therefore save in that table.

Problem is solved. But It would still be nicer if I could have each time a new button.

Anyway has any ideas???

Comment: I know I can work with a JTable in backlinks.java But I need clickable buttons because in the table bl_websitename I can add from where backlink comes, to what url she points, what is the anchor and what is the date... So I can not add those values in a JTable. I need a JFrame Form.

Comment: whats your trying code?